# How to fix ValueError: <__main__.projectile object at 0x0000019B405CE128> is not in list

Tags: python, list, object, valueerror

I'm pretty new to python and I am trying to make a simple space invaders game using pygame but I keep getting this error whenever I try to pop one of the bullets in the list. I have been able to pop the bullets with other collisions but am unable to get this one to work.

```
def hitbaricade():
    global bullets, barricades, enemybullets
    for bullet in bullets:
        for barricade in barricades:
            if abs(barricade.x + (barricade.width//2) - bullet.x) < barricade.width//2 + 2 and abs(barricade.y + barricade.height//2 - bullet.y) < barricade.height//2 + 2:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet)) #this one breaks
                barricades.pop(barricades.index(barricade)) #this one works


    for ebullet in enemybullets:
        for barricade in barricades:
            if abs(barricade.x + (barricade.width//2) - ebullet.x) < barricade.width//2 + 5 and abs(barricade.y + barricade.height - ebullet.y) < defender.height:
                enemybullets.pop(enemybullets.index(ebullet)) #this one breaks
                barricades.pop(barricades.index(barricade)) #this one works
```

Heres where is setup the bullet list the list is declared as an empty list before this

```
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and bulletDelay > 10 and len(bullets) < 1:
            bullets.append(projectile(defender.x + (defender.width//2), 460, -1, 10))
            bulletDelay = 0
```

Heres where I setup the barricade list and the list is decared as an empty list earlier as well

```
def baricadeSetup():
    global barricades
    x = 45
    y = 410
    x2 = x
    width = 5
    height = 5
    loop = 0
    for i in range(0,4):
        for i in range(0,30):
            barricades.append(shield(x,y,width,height))
            loop += 1
            x += 5
            if loop >= 10:
                loop = 0
                x = x2
                y += 5
        x2 += 125
        x = x2
        y = 410
        loop = 0
```

I was trying to get an output where the item in the list would pop but instead I would get the error: ValueError: <**main**.projectile object at 0x000002D6982A5F28> is not in list

Here's the full error message:
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Scripts\Projects\Login System\spaceInvaders.py", line 317, in 
    main()
  File "E:\Python\Scripts\Projects\Login System\spaceInvaders.py", line 298, in main
    hitbaricade()
  File "E:\Python\Scripts\Projects\Login System\spaceInvaders.py", line 250, in hitbaricade
    bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet)) #this one breaks
ValueError: <**main**.projectile object at 0x0000012B51DFE2E8> is not in list

Comment: @FatihAkici When I run that it prints <class 'list'>

Comment: Please share with us what bullets and barricades look like right before you run `hitbaricade()`. Also please paste your full error message.

Comment: @FatihAkici Hello, I added the full error message, what do you mean when saying share "what bullets and barricades look like  right before you run hitbaricade()" do you mean print the list or the index. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you pop the same item over and over again. You should move it from the inner loop.

And you should avoid modifying the list when you are iterating it.

```
def hitbaricade():
    global bullets, barricades, enemybullets
    bullets_removed = set()
    barricades_removed = set()
    for bullet in bullets:
        for barricade in barricades:
            if abs(barricade.x + (barricade.width//2) - bullet.x) < barricade.width//2 + 2 and abs(barricade.y + barricade.height//2 - bullet.y) < barricade.height//2 + 2:
                bullets_removed.add(bullet)
                barricades_removed.add(barricade)
    bullets = [bullet for bullet in bullets if bullet not in bullets_removed]
    barricades = [barricade for barricade in barricades if barricade not in barricades_removed]

    ebullets_removed = set()
    barricades_removed = set()
    for ebullet in enemybullets:
        for barricade in barricades:
            if abs(barricade.x + (barricade.width//2) - ebullet.x) < barricade.width//2 + 5 and abs(barricade.y + barricade.height - ebullet.y) < defender.height:
                ebullets_removed(ebullet)
                barricades_removed(barricade)
    enemybullets = [ebullet for ebullet in enemybullets if ebullet not in ebullets_removed]
    barricades = [barricade for barricade in barricades if barricade not in barricades_removed]
```

Comment: It's only from the programming perspective, please let me know your real purpose so I can give you some algorithm suggestions.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying  to destroy the barricade object and the bullet object when they collide with eachother. Thank you for your help

Comment: @JoshC. Would one bullet hit multiple barricades? In another way, will you remove all barricades if only one bullet hits them all?

Comment: I have multiple barricades clustered together and when I just create a single barricade the error is no longer there. Is there any way to keep multiple barricades? If not thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mean, will one barricade overlap other ones? I add the code by the way. If it doesn't work, please let me know, since I am unable to test it without real data.